# Using buttons to create on screen keyboard - this.value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button `onClick` add its value to a text form. I don't really understand the "this" keyword but I tried using this:

```
function typing(){
    document.getElementById('searchbar').value+=this.value 
}
```

For the `onClick`, nothing happens and there are no errors in console either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 'this' is not what you think, in this case: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/ P.S. try to alert(this) and you will see...

Comment: Oh okay, is there a different keyword i can use to call the value of the button instead? I'm using a script to create the buttons and don't know how to get them to add their value to the search bar when I click them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply bind to click event of the button and add it's value to your text box using this:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('#searchbar').val($(this).val());
});
```

Or if you just want to use plain js, you can pass the value inside the click handler like this:

```
<input type="button" value="A" onclick="doAction(this.value)">
```

And then:

```
function doAction(value) {
    var searchbar = document.getElementById('searchbar');
    searchbar.value = value;
}
```

Here is a plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/AGR29w1g4TzW4udfazMv?p=preview

Comment: I think the line searchbar.value = value doesn't work as the alert(value) gives the correct value but my search box is not updating still.